# Image in Kotlin Kdoc in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kdoc

In JavaDoc you can add an image like this:

```
/**
 * ...The following legend explains these diagrams:
 * <img width="640" height="577" src="https://raw.github.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/Completable.png" alt="">
 */
public class Test {
}
```

How can I achieve the same thing in Kotlin Kdoc?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to put images. Kdoc is much more limited than Javadoc for some reason, and HTML is not supported.

Comment: I agree with you, but maybe this question will stay as a relic of how much time Kotlin will need to add this feature and someone will answer, hey there is a solution now

Comment: Kdoc does not currently support inline images like JavaDoc. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-13687/KDoc-support-inline-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to see the  preview image of the link in Android Studio then `@see` will load and show it :

```
 /**
 * @see <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/Completable.png"/>
 */
```